# How to get first 2 siblings after the match using Xpath1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have the below xml:

```
<book>
  <name id="11" />
  <name id="12" />
  <name id="13" />
  <name id="51" />
  <name id="18" />
  <name id="61" />
  <name id="198" />
  <name id="41" />
</book>
```

I wrote the below Xpath :-

```
/book/*[@id=51]/following-sibling::*
```

Getting output as :

```
<name id="18"/>
<name id="61"/>
<name id="198"/>
<name id="41"/>
```

My goal is to get only :

```
<name id="18"/>
<name id="61"/>
```

I want to select first 2 siblings after the match. How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `position()` do what you require?

`/book/*[@id=51]/following-sibling::*[position()<=2]`

Comment: Yes! That will work. I thought too much,so that I couldn't do that. :)